# componentDidUpdate() make an infinite loop which fetching array of objects by axios and store in redux

Tags: reactjs, redux, axios, components

I have a project which fetching array of objects from server by

axios and store in redux reducer and componentDidUpdate()

make an infinite loop while fetching the objects

compnent:

```
class CategoryList extends Component {
    
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
            
    }

    async componentDidMount() {
        const { fetchSections } = this.props;
        await fetchSections();
        console.log("log from  category componentDidMount" )
    }

    async componentDidUpdate() {
        const { fetchSections } = this.props;
        await fetchSections();
        console.log("log from  category Update" )
    }
    ....

    const mapStateToProps = state => {
        return {
            sections: state.categoryReducer.sections 
    
        }
    }
}
```

in actions file async function which i fetch the objects array from server by axios

```
export const fetchSections = () => {
    return async dispatch => {
        try {
            const response =   await axios.get('http://localhost:8080/sections');
            dispatch({
                type: FETCH_SECTIONS, 
                Sections : response.data.sections
            });
            console.log("log  from fetchSections");
        } catch(err) {
            .... 
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to add certain condition in which you may want to fetch sections again. The current behavior is expected because you are always calling an api which updates redux and again repeats the same thing

Comment: Can u give me example with real code what should I do?